# Failing a Swift initializer without setting stored property

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm writing an application Bluetooth-controlled keynote remote. This will be using AppleScript to control Keynote based on interactions with the CoreBluetooth framework.

Consider this class, which requires the use of an optional `OSALanguage` initializer.

```
class KeynoteController {

    let applescriptLanguage: OSALanguage

    init?() {
        if let applescriptLanguage = OSALanguage(forName: "AppleScript") {
            self.applescriptLanguage = applescriptLanguage
        } else {
            return nil // Compile error on this line
        }
    }

}
```

In this example, I want to fail initializing my `KeynoteController` if there's no `OSALanguage` named `"AppleScript"` (admittedly unlikely, but good design). However, I can't return from my initializer until all stored properties are populated.

I could make `applescriptLanguage` an optional, but since it's non optional and constant if initialization succeeds, this seems like a hack.

What's the correct way to design this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to come from trying to make `applescriptLanguage` a non-optional. The compiler wants it to be assigned a value, even if the object is failing initialization.

Fix it by making it optional property (implicitly unwrapped because it should never actually be nil after initialization).

```
let applescriptLanguage: OSALanguage!
```

This seems like a compiler error to me, but I have no idea what's going on under the hood.

Alternatively, you could temporarily assign it to a dummy value in the else block. This adds extra initialization time and memory allocation, so probably not the best idea, but it'll work if you *really* want to have the property be non-optional.

```
} else {
    self.applescriptLanguage = OSALanguage()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Changing it to a force-unwrapped optional with ! solved it without making it non-constant, apparently since compiler is no longer worried that it's still nil.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I tried it one way, and should have switched it back before messing with implicit unwrapping. Editing the post now.